# What are the benefits of writing code like this?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am reading an article, which is about flutter bloc programming. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial

A Todo Class is defined as below in the article.

```
class Todo {
  final bool complete;
  final String id;
  final String note;
  final String task;

  Todo(this.task, {this.complete = false, String note = '', String id})
      : this.note = note ?? '',
        this.id = id;

  //... other code ...
```

I want to know the benefits of writing constructors like above， comparing to the following way. I found lots of similar situations on that site.

```
Todo(this.task, {this.complete = false, this.note = '', this.id});
```

Thanks.

Comment: in the second form you can use `Todo(note: null)` and `note` will be `null` - if you do that using the first ctor `note` will be an empty `String`

Comment: @pskink Thanks. How about the id field？ Is there any benefit?

Comment: no, its the same

Comment: ok. Thank you, pskink.